# Cluster point equivalent characterizations

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

> Let $(x_n)$ be sequence of elements of a set $X$ and $P(x)$ a
> property. If there exists an infinite subset $J$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such
> that $(\forall n\in J)(P(x_n))$, then we say **that $P$ holds for**
> **infinitely many terms of the sequence**.
>
> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $(x_n)$ a sequence of elements of
> $X$. We call $a\in X$ a **cluster point** of $(x_n)$ if every
> neighbourhood of $a$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $(x_n)$ a sequence of elements of $X$ and $a\in X$. Suppose for each $\varepsilon>0$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$, there exists $n\geq m$ such that $x_n\in B(a;\varepsilon)$ (open ball with center at $a$ and radius $\varepsilon$). I would like to prove that $a$ is a cluster point of $(x_n)$.

I have to construct a subset $J$ of natural numbers with cardinality $\aleph_0$ such that, for every neighbourhood $U$ of $a$, $x_n\in U$ for each $n\in J$. I have not been able to write down such a subset.

I am not able to utilize the assumption. Can you please give me a hint?

Comment: "I have to construct ..." is incorrect, and likely the source of your difficulty. For each nbhd $U$ of $a$ you have to find an infinite $J_U\subset \Bbb N$ such  that $\{x_n: n\in J_U\}\subset U.$ In general, $J_U$ depends on $U.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Construct $J$ recursively. There is an $n_0\ge 0$ such that $x_{n_0}\in B\left(a,1\right)$. Given $n_k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$, there is an $n_{k+1}\ge n_k+1$ such that $x_{n_{k+1}}\in B\left(a,\frac1{m+k+1}\right)$. Let $J=\{n_k:k\ge 0\}$, and show that each open nbhd of $a$ contains every member of $J$ from some point on.

Comment: Does this recursive definition depend on $\varepsilon$? I mean do I make one $J$ for each $\varepsilon$? If $U$ is a neighbourhood of $a$, then there exists $0<r$ such that $B(a;r)\subset U$. Let $m=n_k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then $x_m\in B(a;-)$; what should be the radius of this open ball?

Comment: But $J$ needs to be made in such a way that $x_n$ is an element of every neighbourhood of $a$ for each $n\in J$. Do you mean that I have to pick $\varepsilon$ such that $B(a;\varepsilon)\subset U$ for all neighbourhoods $U$ of $a$?

Comment: okay, got it. Thank you!

Comment: @Pinc: Hang on: I really do need to say more, because what I wrote is *not* enough. The original version of the hint really left a bit too much to the imagination.